# How to make bigger the font of the axis in grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

[image: image of my chart]
I am making a graph in graphana (I am new to using the interface) and I am thinking of putting a graph on a 60-inch screen but the size of the axis is too small in the visualization and I wanted to see if there was no way to change the font size of the axis.
I already tried to configure it with a guide on the internet but I can't find that menu.